# Repetitive sum of a number of columns without for loop in R

Tags: r

I have an matrix of T*12 rows and 3 columns.
For each column, I want to sum the first set of 12 rows, then the second set of 12 rows and so on until the last (T=20) set of 12 rows.

I managed to do it with a for loop (below) but I would like to do it without the loop.

```
T=20
for (i in 1:T){
j <- (i-1)*12+1
Ryear[i,] <- colSums(R[j:(j+11),])
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you provide an example of your matrix too.

Comment: Hi, assuming your dataframe is R `apply(R, 2, function(x) tapply(x, gl(20,12), sum) )` computes the sum of the columns by blocks of 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the matrix to 'array' and then do the 'sum'

```
R1 <- R
dim(R1) <- c(12, 20, 3)
res <- apply(aperm(R1, c(1,3,2)),2, colSums)
identical(res, Ryear) #Ryear based on the results from the OP's code
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 R <- matrix(sample(1:20, 20*12*3, replace=TRUE), nrow=20*12, ncol=3)
 Ryear <- matrix(,nrow=20, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

A dplyr approach based on sample data by @akrun:

```
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(R) %>% 
  group_by(grp = rep(seq_len(20), each = 12)) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))   # add %>% select(-grp) to drop the "grp" column

#Source: local data frame [20 x 4]
#
#   grp  V1  V2  V3
#1    1 136 153 144
#2    2 105 118 155
#3    3  94 149 122
#4    4 110 134 133
#5    5 120 114 102
#6    6 118 122 133
#7    7 116  96 120
#8    8 130 113 113
#9    9 113 140  97
#10  10 135 152 114
#11  11 148 139 148
#12  12 100 153  92
#13  13 136  99 141
#14  14 100 132 124
#15  15 121 139 133
#16  16 124 115 140
#17  17 168 127 129
#18  18 108 110  89
#19  19 115 152 108
#20  20 105 143 134
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of summing, e.g. the 1st column (defining the variables `T` and `R` as in the OP)

```
rowSums(matrix(R[, 1], nrow = T, byrow = TRUE))
```

To do it for all columns of `R`, either use `sapply` or a loop depending on what you want your final outcome to look like, e.g.

```
sapply(1:ncol(R), function(i) rowSums(matrix(R[, i], nrow = T, byrow = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea with the neglected `rowsum` (using akrun's data):

```
n = 12
rowsum(R, rep(seq_len(nrow(R) / n), each = n))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#1   136  153  144
#2   105  118  155
#3    94  149  122
#4   110  134  133
#5   120  114  102
#6   118  122  133
#7   116   96  120
#8   130  113  113
#9   113  140   97
#10  135  152  114
#11  148  139  148
#12  100  153   92
#13  136   99  141
#14  100  132  124
#15  121  139  133
#16  124  115  140
#17  168  127  129
#18  108  110   89
#19  115  152  108
#20  105  143  134
```

Comment: I like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a new column called `group` corresponding to each T value (group of 12 rows).  You can then split on this group to obtain a list of data frames for each T value:

```
R$group <- trunc(c(0:(nrow(R)-1)) / 12)            # assign T group value
R.groups <- split(R, R$group)                      # split 'R' by group
R.sums <- lapply(R.groups, function(x) colSums(x)) # colSums() on each group
```